Is there a way to change the location of .vscode folder in Windows 10?
By launching the setup program of VScode. It defaultly installs the .vsode folder in C:\Users%username%.vscode. By my knowlede, vscode will install extensions in this folder and save user settings in this folder
But I have limited C disk space. So I want this folder located in another disk, like D disk. And VScode can find where it is then install the extensions in .vsocde folder in D disk.
How can I achieve this goal? Thanks inadvance.
What I tried is to copy .vscode in other folder, but it seems not work apparently.
I want to know how to make let .vscode located in D disk.
By the way, My OS is Windows 10. The vscode version I userd is VSCodeSetup-x64-1.89.1.exe (system installer). And I installed it in D disk.

with the CLI option --extensions-dir <dir> you can change the location for extensions, maybe there is also an option to move other parts of VSC settings, workspace settings databases (sqlite3) can blow up sometimes and take a lot of space

When you are installing it, it should ask you where to install VS code. Just choose the appropriate drive to install it on.
As for extensions, I've found this SO answer and it is in the documentation

yeah, I saw this SO answer. But it talked about how to change extensions. Is there a way to directly change .vscode folder location?

From this answer it doesn't appear to be possible but you might be able to move the .vscode folder and then create "hard link" to it like it's explained here, the article it links to leads to is dead, so here's an alternative article I found.
